# PHP ftp_put and remote paths

Tags: php, ftp

Does any of you know what might cause ftp_put to fail when passing a full remote path rather than filename only?

I am asking because according to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php the second parameter is The remote file path but someone apparently had a problem: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php#89986

I would like to avoid having to ftp_chdir to all targets because it costs too much time.

Comment: Where is your code ?? so many things there can make it fail

Comment: My code works fine, just that guy's code from the comment on php.net fails. That is why I am asking if any of you knows what might be causing ftp_put to fail in that case. Does it depend on the FTP server perhaps?